# SagePay Multi Lingual Support Forms Integration

Tags: opayo

This is regarding multi lingual support for SagePay, specifially with .NET.

I am reading "FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_130515.pdf", on page 43 the is mention of a Language field that specifies if a different language is to be used on the payment pages. I have read the template customisation document and understand that I need to create the different languages in the "i18n.xml" file.

My question is how can I send the flag to let the Sage Pay server know which language to use, is the language field a hidden input field?

At the moment I am doing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="FR" />
```

The integration document doesnt specify where to set the Language field value and there is no variable in the .NET Kit to set the language.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the language field needs to form part of your `Crypt` field that is sent to sage pay via the hidden `Crypt` input field.
So it will be something like:

```
myCryptStr += "&Language=FR";
```

It's worth noting that if using their default templates:

> Currently supported languages in the Default templates are :
>   French, German, Spanish, Portuguese, Dutch and English

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it as so, so that others do not waste time reading & answering already answered questions :)

Comment: ok thanks for that. Thats works. What if im using a language other than the default installed language? If I specify a 2 character language code will the language be picked up from what I specify in my custom template?

Comment: I think any language will work, but you will have to add the translations in yourself to your files if they are outside of those listed. You can do this by using their custom templates and editing the `i18n.xml` file. http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/protocol-3-00-additional-fields-transaction-registration

Comment: ok thanks i will try that. like to keep thread open so i can post back how i got on.